# javascript textarea count characters per line

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I'm attempting to count the characters in each line of a textarea.

I've tried to adapt this code for counting syllable http://jsfiddle.net/5Zwkq/19/ with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function $CharCount($input) {
  $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").keyup(function() {

    var arrayOfLines = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").val().match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
    var tempArr = [];
    var $content;
    var char;
    var $result;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfLines.length; i++) {
      $content = arrayOfLines[i];
      $result = $content.val().length;
      tempArr.push($result);
    }

    $("[name=set_" + $input + "_content]").val(tempArr);

  });
}

(function($) {
  $CharCount("a");
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<textarea rows="8" cols="3" class="alignright" name="set_a_syllable_count" readonly="readonly" /></textarea>
<textarea rows="8" cols="30" name="set_a"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.val()` is causing an error in this line:

```
$result = $content.val().length;
```

Removing it properly counts the line lengths (at least in the calculations area).

As for the counter textarea bug, you just got the jQuery selector wrong. Rename your element `set_a_syllable_count` to `set_a_content`.

There is one more problem - when textarea is empty, it throws an error because you are checking an empty regexp result (`null`, to be precise). You simply have to prevent counting code to execute when there are no matched lines:

```
if (arrayOfLines !== null) { ... counting code ... }
```

Fixed code:

```js
function $CharCount($input) {
  $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").keyup(function() {

    var arrayOfLines = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").val().match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
    var tempArr = [];
    var $content;
    var char;
    var $result;

    if (arrayOfLines !== null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfLines.length; i++) {
        $content = arrayOfLines[i];
        $result = $content.length;
        tempArr.push($result);
      }
    }

    $("[name=set_" + $input + "_content]").val(tempArr);

  });
}

(function($) {
  $CharCount("a");
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="8" cols="3" class="alignright" name="set_a_content" readonly="readonly" /></textarea>
<textarea rows="8" cols="30" name="set_a"></textarea>
```

Comment: Worked perfect and thanks for explaining what you did. It helps me get better.

Comment: A year later but, I'm trying to get exactly this result but can't figure out why the counters on the left textarea, are being concatenated by commas.  Where in the code does this happen as I don't see it?

Comment: @JonathanvanClute `tempArr` is an array, so the automatic conversion to a string that happens when setting its contents in the last `.val(tempArr)` call has to concatenate it. The default behavior is to concatenate it with commas. You should fill this textarea with manually concatenated data (`.val(tempArr.join("<concatenation value, eg. space>"))`).

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is:

```js
function $count_how_many_syllables($input) {
  $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").keyup(function (e) {

    var arrayOfLines = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").val().match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
    var tempArr = [];
    var $charsPerLine;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfLines.length; i++) {
      $charsPerLine = arrayOfLines[i].length;
      tempArr.push($charsPerLine);
    }

    $("[name=set_" + $input + "_syllable_count]").val(tempArr.join('\n'));

  }).trigger('keyup');
}

$(function () {
  $count_how_many_syllables("a");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea rows="8" cols="3" class="alignright" name="set_a_syllable_count" readonly="readonly" /></textarea>
<textarea rows="8" cols="30" name="set_a">i would appreciate
any help
at all</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was a little bit too slow but here is some code which imo achieves the same with much less effort.

```js
        function count() {

            var lines = document
                .getElementById("area")
                .value
                .split("\n");

            var lengths = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                var lineLength = lines[i].length;
                document.write(lineLength+ "</br>");
                lengths.push(lineLength);
            }
        }
```

```html
    <textarea id="area"></textarea>
    <br />
    <button onclick="count();">Count</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
    var lines = $(input).val().match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
    var count = [];
    var content;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        content = lines[i].split(" ").join("");
        count.push(content.length);
    }
```

You can also avoid repeat characters to by counted, removing them from each line string:

```
content = content.split(" ").join("");
content = content.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "");
count_no_repeat.push(content.length);
```

Complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/bwnL9Lgg/3/